# JMeter - embedded requests has Bundle.js which in turn triggers more secondary requests - Recursive retrieving of embedded resource requests

Tags: reactjs, jmeter, embedded-resource

My JMeter version is apache-jmeter-5.4.1.
I am trying to set up a HTTP Request something like this on a react based website:

1. HTTP Request - GET http://YYY.YYY.YYYY/141719  (With Retrieve Embedded Resources checked)
   When I run this, I can see JMeter captures embedded resource requests (Secondary requests) which are like *.css, *.js

**Second set of embedded resource requests :**
However one of these secondary requests called - bundle.xxxxxxx.js creates another set of embedded resource requests to the server which retrieve further *.js files as part of the Request Initiator chain.
While the name of this file itself is randomly generated like, ex., bundle.0787f963ab0ac67dd7d4.js

The browser of course parses this bundle.xxxxxxx.js immediately and gets all the embedded resources/requests(including chunk.*.js)

My problem is how do I replicate this behaviour using JMeter, for the second set of embedded resource requests also to be triggered. At the moment, I can only achieve capturing the first set of embedded resource requests. This does not give me true load test results as the second set has more traffic to the server. Is there a way to recursively Retrieve all embedded resources.

Our application under test is based on React JS.

Answer (score 0):

As per [JMeter project main page](https://jmeter.apache.org/):

> JMeter is not a browser, it works at protocol level. As far as web-services and remote services are concerned, JMeter looks like a browser (or rather, multiple browsers); however JMeter does not perform all the actions supported by browsers. **In particular, JMeter does not execute the Javascript found in HTML pages.** Nor does it render the HTML pages as a browser does (it's possible to view the response as HTML etc., but the timings are not included in any samples, and only one sample in one thread is ever displayed at a time).

There are several initiator types:

- parser (index, styles, fonts, etc.) - these guys will be captured by embedded resources downloading functionality. All below will need to be handled somehow else
- redirect
- script
- other

So if you need to mimic a number of HTTP requests which originate from JavaScript it will be required to replicate the logic from this JavaScript code in JMeter.

There is a minimal chance that you will be able to copy and paste the JavaScript into [JSR223 PostProcessor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) however most likely it relies on certain objects like [navigator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Navigator), [window](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window) or [XMLHttpRequest](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest) so it's highly likely that you will have to re-write it in Groovy. Once you have enough data to properly build HTTP Request samplers most probably you will need to put them under the [Parallel Controller](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-to-use-the-parallel-controller-in-jmeter/)

Another option is going for [WebDriver Sampler](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/WebDriverSampler/) and use real browsers for your tests but be aware that browsers are very resources intensive comparing to HTTP Request samplers